# Webpack 2 svg files give 404 error

Tags: javascript, css, svg, webpack-2

Started working with webpack. In one of my css files I have an url to an svg file, but by using webpack I get 404 error when trying to load this file, tried few loaders [first](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/597), [second](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/226) and [last](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/404). Have no idea why its not working, can some one help me or give some info?

EDIT

```
entry: [
    './src\\main\\resources\\static\\webpack-js\\header.js'
],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main/resources/static/dist'),
    publicPath: '/src/main/resources/static/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'EntryPoint',
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: ['buble-loader'],
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        }
    ],
}
```

This is my module from `webpack.config.js`. I am using css file that is `required` in `header.js` (entry file). Now in the css file I have lines like this

```
.vismaicon-menu.vismaicon-info:before {
    background-image: url(/static/css/img/vismaicons/top_menu/menu_info.svg);
}
```

As I mentioned I tried few things to load svg files but I'm getting 404 error. And yes url is correct and files are there, it works without webpack. Everything other than svg works in css files and I get things from it.

Comment: Please show your config and how you are using the svg.

Comment: Here you go added few lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Changed my `Loaders` for `svg` to this one and giving bigger limit solved my problem.

```
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=1000000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
},
```